# Can't find a proper regex for parsing the string

Tags: javascript, php, regex

So I have the string in the following format

```
 [randomstring] [randomtest]

 [randomstring] [texttext...
Data: 
{"data}]
```

So the only thing in common for every line is that all text is stored inside exactly 2 square brackets per line, `[text1][text2]` . The problem is when the text goes on multiple lines:

```
[text1][text2
text3
text4]
```

So I'm looking for a regex to match every `[][]` pair, per line and came up with this:

https://regex101.com/r/vI0oF6/1

As you can see, only the first line is matched and not the second. Is there a better way ?

Comment: instead of `.` use `[^\]]` ( which includdes newline character)

Comment: Instead of .* to use [^\]]* ?

Comment: Is this the content of a file? How many lines do you have in a real case? (A single regex might not be the best option on a large input.)

Comment: Please include your regex here directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options. Use the `s` modifier to match newlines with `.`, or simply accept newlines inside the square brackets.

### With the s modifier

```
 /(\[.+?\]+\s?\[.+?\])/gs
```

https://regex101.com/r/vI0oF6/5

### Without the s-modifier

```
/(\[(?:.|\n)+?\]+\s?\[(?:.|\n)+?\])/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/vI0oF6/6

*Note that I'm creating a non-capturing group with the `(?:.|\n)` syntax.*

Also, notice that I used the non-greedy matching token `?` inside the square brackets to make it stop matching when it first meets a square bracket instead of being greedy and also matching square brackets with the dot. Visualized, the `?` after a quantifier (`*` or `+`) does this:

#### Without `?`, `.+` is greedy and matches until the last met `]`

```
# Simple example: \[.+\]
[foo][bar]
^--------^
```

#### With `?`, `.+` is non-greedy and matches only until the first met `]`

```
# Simple example: \[.+?\]
[foo][bar]
^---^
```

Comment: yeah but as you can see, for the first line, it matches [text1] and [text2] as a 2 separate matches, instead of one [text1][text2]

Comment: Aha. I thought that was the goal. Updated the answer @Zed.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. Your updated answer is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use `s` modifier to include new lines (Dot matches new line characters).
https://regex101.com/r/vI0oF6/2

Comment: That would match everything as one big string, instead of each [][] separetely

Answer (score 0):

Try with this expression `(\[[^\]]+\])`

http://regexr.com/3duup

Comment: That regex matches each square bracket individually, instead of both of them per line.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the one you are looking for `(\[[^\]]+\])`.

It matches a `[` followed by one or more characters other than `]`, followed by a `]`. If you want to match ones without anything inside the brackets as well, use `*` instead of `+`.

Note: My understanding is that you need to match `[text1]` and `[text2]` from first line, `[text1]` and

```
[text2
text3
text4]
```

from lines 3 to 5 when input is

```
[text1] [text2]

[text1][text2
text3
text4]
```